# Electron adding files to public folder after build fails

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pdf, electron, pdf.js

I'm building an electron app with vue.js + vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder that shows the structure of the public folder which includes a "pdf" folder with PDF files.
I use pdf.js to show the pdfs.
To have that "pdf" folder later in my my app I copy that folder with

```
extraFiles: [
    {
        from: "./public/pdf",
        to: "pdf"
    }
```

[image: app shows folder structure and included pdf files]

The app shows all folders and included pdf files.
When I click on one pdf name a popup opens and shows the PDF.
Works great in development and in the final build.

I read the folder with this function:

```js
readdir () {
     
      var devPath = path.join(__static, '/pdf/Anbau')
      console.log("devPath development : ", devPath);
      
      var readFiles = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          fs.readdir(devPath, (err,files) => {
            if(err) {
              alert('Lesen fehlgeschlagen!', {type: 'error'})
              reject(err);
            } else {
              resolve(files);

              this.list = files;
              console.log('this.list: ', this.list, this.list.length)
            }
          });
        });

    },
```

The problem is now, when I add new folders and pdfs to that
public folder **after** the app is built, the app shows the new folders and pdfs, but if I click on the generated name "someNewPDF.pdf", pdf.js throws an error.

The console output with the path of the pdf is correct.
I found out that ONLY the files that exist before the build process are later accessible. When I rename a pdf, electron neither can show that file.
It seems like electron creates a map of the files when building the app and later it can't be changed.

So my question is:
What can I do to let the app read dynamically a folder that can be filled / expanded later.

The idea is, that the user can throw his pdf files into a folder and that can be viewed via my app.

I'm quite new in vue and electron.

Answer (score 0):

i've found a solution:
the client can put his files now in a folder "pdf" on the desktop. Inside of this folder are also the necessary files of PDF.js.
The path to the desktop on MAC and Windows is

```
const desktopPath = app.getPath('desktop')
```

so now i can

```
window.open('file://' + desktopPath + '/pdf/web/viewer.html?file=' + url)
```

while **url** holds the path to the pdf.